# How do I speed up my snake temporary whenever the snake ate a boost?

Tags: javascript

I wanna speed up my snake temporary whenever the snake ate a boost (blue colour).

Appreciated if there's any feedback and modification about it

```
if (ateFood) {
  this.food.active = false;
  this.game.score += 10;
  this.$score.innerText = this.game.score;
  this.soundEffects.score.play();
  this.snake.pop();
} else if (ateBoost) {
  this.boost.active = false;
  this.soundEffects.score.play();
  speed = 50;
  //stuck at here
  this.snake.pop();
} else {
  this.snake.pop();
}
```

[Full code can be see at here](https://codepen.io/agent501/pen/ExKYeyN)

Answer (score 0):

After you speed up the snake with `speed = 50` which works, you can `setTimeout(function(){ speed = oldSpeed; }, millisecondsOfBoost);` in the next line. So if the default speed is 10 and you want to boost for 2 seconds it would be `setTimeout(function(){ speed = 10; }, 2000);`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but the thing is that i set the speed = 50 the snake still moving at default speed after ate them. Maybe you wanna check out the full code and play a bit?

Comment: Okay, so I took another look at the code and it seems like the speed variable is the interval speed for the main loop that runs the game. The problem is that the interval speed cannot be changed mid-interval on the fly. Whatever the speed variable was at the start will remain. To fix this, you can either remove and remake the setInterval everytime the speed changes or more optimally, rewrite the code to use window.requestAnimationFrame(), to run the loop (see more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 0):

In the else if statement, you did.
**speed = 50** which is hard coded which makes your speed static. But in JavaScript, to increment or decrement, you need to make the **speed += 50** which means *speed = speed + 50* and to deferment which can be **speed -=50** which means **speed = speed - 50**.
You may later decrease the speed after some seconds though.

So In the else if statement, you can decrease the speed after Maybe 10 seconds by **setting a timeout**.

```
speed = 50;
setTimeout(() => {
       speed = 10
}, 10000)
```

After setting your speed to 50, the set Timeout which takes two parameters, a function and time returns the speed to 10 in the function after 10000ms which is 10secs

Comment: Appreciated the reply but I'd tried it and is not working. Maybe is because my code structure